# are apps also synced when I used grsync?

Tags: 16.04, rsync

When I back up my home folder to an external drive are all my apps and apps preferences synced as well? In other words, if I reinstall the base OS system from scratch, can I restore everything ( including apps ) exactly as I had before ?

Comment: Mostly yes but you'll also need several other directories for the full backup besides `/home` such as `/etc`, `/usr`, `/opt`.

Comment: No when you back up home you ate only saving usr settings. You need more than suggested above

Answer (score 0):

Your user home folder contains your personal data, *and* user-specific application settings. The latter are stored in hidden files/folders, i.e., files/folders of which the name starts with a dot.

When reinstalling the base system and restoring your previous home folder, you still will need to reinstall any applications that do not come with a default install yourself. However, the applications will continue to use the user-specific application stored in your restored home folder.

There is a caveat when reinstalling this way. Not only your login, but also the number assigned to your account, i.e., the user id, UID, must be the same on the new install. This will be the case if you create the accounts in the same order as you did when previously installing the system.